# Router in Angular 2 only responding to root element call

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I've set up my routing as follows.

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { Demo11 } from "demo/demo11";
import { Demo12 } from "demo/demo12";

export const Routing: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: Demo11 },
  { path: "plopp", component: Demo12 }
];
```

My main module looks like this.

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavBar, Demo11, Demo12],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(Routing)],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "/" }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For some reason, it seems that the root is hit properly but the URL */plopp* doesn't bring any difference. What can I be missing in the set up and how do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't bring any difference" ? What's the content of your components ? Your path should be `plopp` without the `./`

Comment: @YounesM The contents are the texts *demo11* and *demo12*. I only see the former, even if I punch in a different URL.

Comment: @YounesM According to a book, it'd create a relative path and not from the root. Perhaps I missed something.

Comment: Do the URL properly change or does it redirect you to the home path ?

Comment: Well, when I enter *localhost/plopp* I get *Cannot GET /plopp*. When I tried *localhost/#/plopp*, I didn't get the error but nothing changed on the screen.

Comment: You don't create a relative path, you declare your routes paths. You're not importing anything you're just saying to the app : when the URL is /plopp use that component.

Comment: @YounesM Got it. Perhaps the diagnostics of mine were faulty. Perhaps I'm supposed to use *localhost/plopp* and not get the error I'm getting. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot it? What to verify?

Comment: Have you placed the <router-outlet> ?

Comment: @KerimEmurla Yes, of course. Otherwise, the component at the root path wouldn't render at all. The issue seems to be that the component deeper in on the path doesn't render as I get no change or when I get *Cannot GET /plopp*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I've set up an exactly the same project as yours with 2 demo components and my routing works just fine, do you want me to upload it somewhere so you can check if you are missing something?

Comment: @KerimEmurla Would you be a sport and do that, please? I've made iwork by trying changing everything in the provider back and forth but I don't feel confident about its robustness. Please feel welcome to upload the working POC, by all means.

Comment: Yes, of course. I've created the project using angular-cli and created 2 components for testing and I've set up the routing with the provider you are using. Just run npm-install on it if you want to test it out in the browser.
This is the link for downloading the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B91nbnJselt5S28zV2FTeXE3Y1U

P.S: Also let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: @KerimEmurla You need to post it as a reply so it can get accepted as an answer, please.

Comment: @KonradViltersten How do you test/run your app? Is it with lite-server or with plain nodejs/express? Assuming your no error in your app, the issue is the server/serving side.

Comment: @KonradViltersten sure thing, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created the test project the same way as yours with 2 demo components where the structure of the app looks like this:

```
├───e2e
└───src
    ├───app
    │   ├───first-component
    │   └───second-component
    ├───assets
    └───environments
```

Then I created *app-routing.module* where I configured all the routing of the app and then import it in *app.module*.

This is how my app-routing.module looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { FirstComponent } from './first-component/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './second-component/second.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: FirstComponent },
    { path: 'demo', component: SecondComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*FirstComponent and SecondComponent are the demo components I've created.*

And this is how my *app.module* looks like:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './first-component/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './second-component/second.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstComponent,
    SecondComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```